# multinom: how to get the number of observations

Tags: r, nnet

I am using `multinom` from `nnet` to create a logistic model from a massive clinical database. The syntax I'm using is:

```
library(nnet)
fit=multinom(group ~ sex + age + var3 + var4,
            data=d, na.action = na.omit)
```

Now, each row (a patient) has a different number of NAs, as not all clinical data were recorded for all patients, and it is not clear to me if the model only uses those rows for which all of the variables do not contain any NAs.
More in general, it would be useful to obtain the Ns of observations that the model is based on, which I suspect is smaller that the number of rows of my dataframe (N of patients).
I have looked everywhere but I don't seem to be able to find how to do this.

Comment: `nrow(na.omit(d))`

Comment: thanks but this does not work as it looks at all vars, not only the ones in the model.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `nrow(residuals(fit))` should work (pointed out in comments that `residuals()` returns a matrix).

If you want to explore the data set that was used to fit the model, you can do:

```
mf <- model.frame(group ~ sex + age + var3 + var4, data=d,
                  na.action=na.omit)
```

(this is how `multinom` processes your data) and then count the number of rows, tabulate the number of observations in different categories for different variables (e.g. `table(mf$var3)`), etc.. `lapply(mf,table)` should tabulate the number of observations by category for every variable.

You might find the `describe` function from the `Hmisc` package useful:

```
Hmisc::describe(group ~ sex + age + var3 + var4, data=d)
```

Comment: thanks for this. this I guess gives me the total number of observations used. Is there a way to look at the number of observations per category? For example, let's say that var2 has 3 levels, yes, no and maybe. I have 2000 yes, 1000 no, and 4000 maybe. Can I know this for each var?

Comment: Thank you Professor Bolker, this is invaluable

Comment: @Ben Bolker It seems one just needs `nrow(residuals(fit))` (as `residuals` is a matrix of dimensions N_obs*number of multinomial categories, and so its `length` is their product)